# Jinja2 template return nothing if variable is undefined

Tags: jinja2, quickbase

I'm using Quickbase Pipelines trying to get some information to show in a notification email only if that variable (call rating) is defined. I've tried:

```
Audio Time: {{c.audio_time_min|int}}
{% if c.call_rating != '' %}
Call Rating: {{c.call_rating}}
{% else %}
''
{% endif %}
```

and

```
Audio Time: {{c.audio_time_min|int}}
{% if c.call_rating is defined %}
Call Rating: {{c.call_rating}}
{% else %}
''
{% endif %}
```

But I keep getting this as the response when that call rating variable is blank:

Audio Time: 21
Call Rating:

What I want is to not include that line at all, so:

Audio Time: 21

Comment: Just wanted to clarify before I answered - is the goal to show "Audio TIme: 21" when the [Call Rating] had a value in it, otherwise don't write anything?

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work:

```
Audio Time: {{c.audio_time_min|int}}
{% if c.call_rating not none %}
Call Rating: {{c.call_rating}}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quickbase Pipelines didn't let me save it with the "not none" test. What did work was:

```
Audio Time: {{c.audio_time_min|int}}
{% if c.call_rating %}
Call Rating: {{c.call_rating}}
{% endif %}
```

The result there if the Call Rating field is blank is just:

Audio Time: 23